# Jquery validator set value blank

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have developed a mobile app using the jquery-mobile framework. I need the value entered by user in input field. `<input type="number" size="35" value="Enter a Number..." step="0.01" placeholder="Enter a Number...">`
If any number is entered then it's value gets successfully but if entered anything except a number it becomes invalid and its value showing as blanks, Is there any way to get entered value?

Comment: If you're using jq validate, you will have to add a special rule, because jQM wraps input in a different container/div. Or, you can tell jQM not to enhance any number input.

Comment: Where is the demo?  Show the rest of the code that makes this work.  How do you expect to get any help when we cannot even reproduce the issue without constructing something from scratch?

Comment: Your `input` **must** contain a `name` attribute or the jQuery Validate plugin cannot keep track of it.

Comment: we will not able to get the value for number filed if value isn't a valid numeric value. Read this
https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#number-state-%28type=number%29

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#number-state-%28type=number%29

Comment: What does this question have to do with backbone.js? How is it related?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that related to something with jqmobile.

Even if you add the [clearBtn](https://api.jquerymobile.com/textinput/#option-clearBtn) widget, when you input invalid strings it's not showing:

```js
document.querySelector('input[type="number"]').addEventListener('change', function() {console.log(this.value)});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

<input type="number" size="35" value="Enter a Number..." step="0.01" placeholder="Enter a Number..." data-clear-btn="true" />
```

Comment: Yes you are correct. I got answer from : https://forum.jquery.com/topic/read-invalid-value-of-input